# Making a script for sorting photos based on tags faster

Tags: r, optimization, tags, vectorization, photo

Hi I have no idea if this is a legitimate question for SO.
But I have a script i made for sorting photos into folders based on tags. It uses the `exifr` package to do this.

However, it's running very slow. I've tried to improve it using [guides](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/01/strategies-to-speedup-r-code/) but what I ever I make ends up not working. Is there someone with understanding of vectorization and or optimization that could give point to some suggestions.
Thanks!

```
#----- Imports ----
library(exifr)

# ---------- Functions ----------
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))
tagcatcher <- function(dat){
  tags <- c()
  for (tagNameTry in keywords_names )  {
    if (tagNameTry %in% names(dat)) {
      xs <- dat[tagNameTry]
      if (typeof(xs) == "list") {
        xs <- xs[[1]]
        l <- length(xs[[1]])
        x <- c()
        for (i in 1:l) {
          x <- c(x,xs[[1]][i])
        }
      } else {
        x <- xs
      }
      tags <- c(tags,x)
    }
  }
  tags <- unique(tags)
  return(tags)
}

# ----------- Settings ----------
ss <- "/"
haystacks <- c("H:MyPhotos")
organizedMediaPhotos <- "V:/Photos"
all_files <- list.files(haystacks,recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
keywords_names <- c("Category","XPKeywords","Keywords")
ctags <- list.dirs(organizedMediaPhotos)[list.dirs(organizedMediaPhotos) %!in% organizedMediaPhotos]
current_tags <- c()

for (ctag in ctags) {
  x <- strsplit(ctag,"/")
  x <- x[[1]]
  x <- x[length(x)]
  current_tags <- c(current_tags,x)
}

# Main Loop - That Needs to be faster
for (cur_file in all_files) {
  print(cur_file)
  cur_dat <- read_exif(cur_file,tags=keywords_names)
  tags <- tagcatcher(cur_dat)
  for (tag in tags) {
    tag_folder <- paste(organizedMediaPhotos,ss,tag,sep="")
    if (tag %!in% current_tags) {
      dir.create(tag_folder)
      print(paste("creating tag folder: ",tag_folder))
    }
    pic_path <- paste(tag_folder,ss,basename(cur_file),sep="")
    if (!file.exists(pic_path)) {
      file.copy(cur_file,pic_path)
      print(paste("moved file from ",cur_file, " to ", pic_path))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One general comment is that you’re growing a (potentially very large?) vector; that’s indeed (unnecessarily) slow. Another, unrelated comment: please don’t write your non-syntactic variable names as strings. The fact that R allows this is a mistake that just leads to confusion. Instead, use backticks as recommended in the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html) (under “Names and Identifiers”). Furthermore, you can shorten the definition of `\`%!in%\`` to `\`%!in%\` = Negate(\`%in%\`)`.

Comment: Have to done any benchmarking to see which steps in the loop are the slowest?

Comment: it must be the "read_exif(cur_file,tags=keywords_names)"

Comment: `read_exif` can accept a vector of file names.  So, if there is a noticable overhead to calling the function, moving the call outside the "process the current file" loop may be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try

```
for x in *.jpg; do
  d=$(date -r "$x" +%Y-%m-%d)
  mkdir -p "$d"
  mv -- "$x" "$d/"
done
```

For powershell:

```
Param(
    [string]$source, 
    [string]$dest, 
    [string]$format = "yyyy/yyyy_MM/yyyy_MM_dd"
)

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

function Get-File-Date {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        $object
    )

    $dir = $shell.NameSpace( $object.Directory.FullName )
    $file = $dir.ParseName( $object.Name )

    # First see if we have Date Taken, which is at index 12
    $date = Get-Date-Property-Value $dir $file 12

    if ($null -eq $date) {
        # If we don't have Date Taken, then find the oldest date from all date properties
        0..287 | ForEach-Object {
            $name = $dir.GetDetailsof($dir.items, $_)

            if ( $name -match '(date)|(created)') {
            
                # Only get value if date field because the GetDetailsOf call is expensive
                $tmp = Get-Date-Property-Value $dir $file $_
                if ( ($null -ne $tmp) -and (($null -eq $date) -or ($tmp -lt $date))) {
                    $date = $tmp
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $date
}

function Get-Date-Property-Value {
    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param (
        $dir,
        $file,
        $index
    )

    $value = ($dir.GetDetailsof($file, $index) -replace "`u{200e}") -replace "`u{200f}"
    if ($value -and $value -ne '') {
        return [DateTime]::ParseExact($value, "g", $null)
    }
    return $null
}

Get-ChildItem -Attributes !Directory $source -Recurse | 
Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing $_"

    $date = Get-File-Date $_

    if ($date) {
    
        $destinationFolder = Get-Date -Date $date -Format $format
        $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $destinationFolder   

        # See if the destination file exists and rename until we get a unique name
        $newFullName = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $_.Name
        if ($_.FullName -eq $newFullName) {
            Write-Host "Skipping: Source file and destination files are at the same location. $_"    
            return
        }

        $newNameIndex = 1
        $newName = $_.Name

        while (Test-Path -Path $newFullName) {
            $newName = ($_.BaseName + "_$newNameIndex" + $_.Extension) 
            $newFullName = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $newName  
            $newNameIndex += 1   
        }

        # If we have a new name, then we need to rename in current location before moving it.
        if ($newNameIndex -gt 1) {
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName
        }

        Write-Host "Moving $_ to $newFullName"

        # Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
        if (!(Test-Path $destinationPath)) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destinationPath
        }

        robocopy $_.DirectoryName $destinationPath $newName /mo
```

PS: I had tried this a few years back and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You can change your if command to something like this:

```
if [[ "$t" =~ IMG_+[0-9]{8}[a-zA-Z]*$ ]]
```

The `=~` is a regular expression comparison operator which is introduced in bash version 3 and above.

By using this if statement you can catch names like IMG_11111111alphabets.ext. You can play with it and customize it according to your needs. For more information have a look at this: Bash's regular expression